# How to figure what commands are scheduled to run by 'at'?

Tags: linux, job-scheduling

I am trying `atq` to see what job is scheduled to run.

```
$ atq
19    Tue Mar  1 08:00:00 2016
```

But the number 19 is not very helpful. Is there a way to see what commands will be run by job 19? Thanks.

Comment: Not a programming question, try  http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=active

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
at -c <jobid>
at -c 19
```